# How to query a database using Spring 4 MVC PathVariable parameter

Tags: java, sql, spring, api, vertica

**Problem to solve:** I am trying to query a database based on the parameter given within a `@RequestMapping` API call.

---

**Piece of my current code where I face errors:**

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/{serialNumber}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void searchByStudent(@PathVariable("serialNumber") String serialNumber) {
        SqlRowSet resultSet = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("SELECT * FROM STORE_ITEMS WHERE SERIALNUMBER = :serialNumber");
        System.out.println(resultSet);
    }
```

---

This is the **error I receive when accessing the URL** via Postman (in the browser):

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM STORE_ITEMS WHERE SERIALNUMBER = :serialNumber]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near ":"

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM STORE_ITEMS WHERE SERIALNUMBER = :serialNumber]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near ":"

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM STORE_ITEMS WHERE SERIALNUMBER = :serialNumber]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near ":"
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM STORE_ITEMS WHERE SERIALNUMBER = :serialNumber]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near ":"
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:91)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:415)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:470)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(JdbcTemplate.java:511)
    com.company.project.controller.DatabaseController.searchBySerialNumber(DatabaseController.java:64)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near ":"
    com.vertica.util.ServerErrorData.buildException(Unknown Source)
    com.vertica.dataengine.VDataEngine.prepareImpl(Unknown Source)
    com.vertica.dataengine.VDataEngine.prepare(Unknown Source)
    com.vertica.dataengine.VDataEngine.prepare(Unknown Source)
    com.vertica.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeNoParams(Unknown Source)
    com.vertica.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:454)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:404)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:470)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(JdbcTemplate.java:511)
    com.company.project.controller.DatabaseController.searchBySerialNumber(DatabaseController.java:64)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

com.vertica.support.exceptions.SyntaxErrorException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near ":"
    com.vertica.util.ServerErrorData.buildException(Unknown Source)
    com.vertica.dataengine.VDataEngine.prepareImpl(Unknown Source)
    com.vertica.dataengine.VDataEngine.prepare(Unknown Source)
    com.vertica.dataengine.VDataEngine.prepare(Unknown Source)
    com.vertica.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeNoParams(Unknown Source)
    com.vertica.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:454)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:404)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:470)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(JdbcTemplate.java:511)
    com.company.project.controller.DatabaseController.searchBySerialNumber(DatabaseController.java:64)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 logs.
```

---

**Error within my output console:**

```
INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
```

---

**Additional Information:**

- Database being used: Vertica (I am not sure if this may be the issue, based on the output console)
- The resultSet would contain roughly five figures worth of objects

---

**Question:** How would I be able to resolve this? I understand it is not the most secure way of querying, but I am trying to make sure my logic works first. Additionally, would there be a potentially better way to use the jdbcTemplate to query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call a method which creates a simple `Statement`, not `PreparedStatement`, yet you are trying to use parameters.

From the javadoc

> Execute a query for a SqlRowSet, given static SQL.
>
> Uses a JDBC Statement, not a PreparedStatement. If you want to execute a static query with a PreparedStatement, use the overloaded queryForRowSet method with null as argument array.

I have never really used this way to query a DB. As you said, this might not be the safest way to do so, let alone the most comfortable. But try to use the overloaded `queryForRowSet` method

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/{serialNumber}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void searchByStudent(@PathVariable("serialNumber") String serialNumber) {
    SqlRowSet resultSet = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("SELECT * FROM STORE_ITEMS WHERE SERIALNUMBER = ?", new Object[] {serialNumber});
    System.out.println(resultSet);
}
```